# How to show loading just only a particular post?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

[image]

```
<tbody>
 {userAllArticle.slice(0, visible).map((article) =>
  <tr key={article.id}>
   <Link to={"/article/" + article.id} onClick={scrollToTop}>
    <td><p>{article.title.substring(0, 60)}...</p></td>
  </Link>
   <td>{article.community_title}</td>
   <td>{moment(article.created_at.split('T')[0]).format('MMMM D YYYY')}</td>
   <td>
 {loader ? <p>...Deleting..</p>
   :
  <ul>
   <li><Link style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} className="delet-btn" onClick={() => 
     deleteArticle(article.id)}>Delete</Link></li>
    </ul>}
  </td>
 </tr>)}
</tbody>
```

When I click the delete button I see ...deleting... every post that I have. I want to show ..deleting... to that particular post that the delete was clicked.

Comment: You need a loader array to go along with your articles

Comment: Can you suggest me some demo codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick way to resolve it.

```
let [loader,setLoader] = useState(null) 

const deleteArticle= async (id)=>{
    setLoader(id)
      //perform required here
    setLoader(null)
}


.......
.......
{loader===article.id ? <p>...Deleting..</p>
   :
  <ul>
   <li><Link style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} className="delet-btn" onClick={() => 
     deleteArticle(article.id)}>Delete</Link></li>
    </ul>}
......
......
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to have a loader variable for every element of your userAllArticle.  You can do this with Arrays, Objects, Sets, or any data structure you want, the implementation will be almost the same.

For sake of simplicity, I will assume that you have IDs available for your posts.

With Sets:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(new Set());

const doDelete = async id => {
    loading.add(id);
    setLoading(loading);
    await doNetworkOperation(id);
    loading.remove(id);
    setLoading(loading);
}

return ( 
<div>
 {articles.map(a => {
    const isLoading = loading.has(a.id);
    // Continue from here
 })}  
</div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "key" of  and article id, if are same then you can print ...Deleting